# Minimize $S=\frac{a}{b} + 2\sqrt{\frac{b}{c}+1} + 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{a}+1}$ under $a=\max\{a,b,c\}$ and $a,b,c>0$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a, b, c > 0$ and $a \geqslant b, a \geqslant c$.Find the minimum value of $$S=\frac{a}{b} + 2\sqrt{\frac{b}{c}+1} + 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{a}+1}.$$

From Diamonds in Mathmetical Inequalities, Tran Phuong

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: can you tell me the minimum value ?

Comment: I got $1+2\sqrt2+3\sqrt[3]2$

Comment: Please write the maximum of {a,b,c} by a different letter...otherwise it is confusing for us....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By AM-GM, $1+x\geq 2x^{\frac12}$ for all $x>0$, so
$$S\geq \frac{a}{b}+2\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{\frac14}+3\sqrt[3]{2}\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}.$$
Using weighted AM-GM, we get
$$S\geq (1+2\sqrt2+3\sqrt[3]2)\left(\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{\frac{2\sqrt2}{4}}\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{\frac{3\sqrt[3]{2}}{6}}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+2\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt[3]{2}}}$$
or
$$S\geq (1+2\sqrt2+3\sqrt[3]2)\left(\frac{a^{1-\frac{3\sqrt[3]2}{6}}}{b^{1-\frac{2\sqrt2}{4}}c^{\frac{2\sqrt2}{4}-\frac{3\sqrt[3]2}{6}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+2\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt[3]{2}}}\,.$$
Since $a\geq b$ and $a\geq c$, we obtain
$$S\geq 1+2\sqrt2+3\sqrt[3]2.$$
It is easy to see that the equality holds iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: can you give me a proof of the weighted am-gm inequality ? great solution.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Proofs_of_AM-GM